# Easiest way to solve this inequality? $m^2-mn+n^2+m-n>0$ for $m,n \in \mathit Z^+$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality, integers, sums-of-squares

The problem in question is to prove:

> $m^2-mn+n^2+m-n>0$ for $m,n \in \mathit Z^+$.

What is the easiest/most consistent way to deal with such problems? Is there any identity that can be applied when we only care about the positive integers?

Thanks.

Comment: THe first three terms look a lot like $(m-n)^2$. I don't know if that gets you anywhere, but it's something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$
m^2 -mn +n^2 + m -n = (m-n)^2 + mn + m -n = (m -n)^2 + n(m-1) + m
$$
Since $m,n \in Z^+$, the first and second terms are $\ge 0$, the third is $\gt 0$ so the sum is $\gt 0$.

This is certainly a special case treatment; but even though there are some common idioms here, I don't think you can come up with a general way to treat such problems.

Answer (score 5):

The hint:

$$m^2-mn+n^2+m-n=\frac{1}{2}((m+1)^2+(n-1)^2+(m-n)^2)-1.$$
Now, prove that:
$$(m+1)^2+(n-1)^2+(m-n)^2\geq4.$$

Answer (score 3):

Playing around, as usual.

$\begin{array}\\
m^2-mn+n^2+m-n
&=\frac12(2m^2-2mn+2n^2)+m-n
\qquad\text{I've done these steps before}\\
&=\frac12(m^2-2mn+n^2+m^2+n^2+2m-2n)\\
&=\frac12((m-n)^2+m^2+2m+n^2-2n)\\
&=\frac12((m-n)^2+m^2+2m+1+n^2-2n+1-2)\\
&=\frac12((m-n)^2+(m+1)^2+(n-1)^2-2)\\
&\ge\frac12((2)^2-2)
\qquad\text{use } m \ge 1\\
&= 1\\
\end{array}
$